# Need to display layout in fragment -android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to display fragment layout when the user clicks an item in navigation drawer.

Activity class : -

```
Fragment fragment = new PreferencesFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment)
    .commit();

mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
setTitle(mNavItems.get(position).mTitle);

// Close the drawer
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerPane);
```

In fragment class:-

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scorefragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //fetching results from db
 }
```

My problem is, it is displaying an exception like

```
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:248)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:905)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1454)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
02-22 10:55:24.113: E/AndroidRuntime(31725):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Activity layout file containing the navigation drawer list

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">   
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#F5F5DC">

   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/thirteenone"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/thirteentwo"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>



             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:weightSum="3"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                 <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/thumb_button_3"
                     android:layout_width="100dp"
                     android:layout_height="200dp"
                     android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_3"
                     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                     android:src="@drawable/thirteenthree"
                     android:layout_weight="1" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView6"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1" />

                 <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/thumb_button_4"
                     android:layout_width="100dp"
                     android:layout_height="200dp"
                     android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_4"
                     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                     android:src="@drawable/thirteenfour"
                     android:layout_weight="1" />

             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1" 
                 android:weightSum="3">

                 <CheckBox
                     android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="C" 
                      android:layout_weight="1" />

                  <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView4"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_weight="1"  />
                 <CheckBox
                     android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="D"
                     android:layout_weight="1"  />

             </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description_zoom_touch_close" />

  </FrameLayout>

  </ScrollView>

  <!-- The navigation drawer -->
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

  <!-- Profile Box -->

  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profileBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:padding="8dp" >

   <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/avatar"
     android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navList"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Scorefragment layout file.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:weightSum="3" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/bone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3f51b5"
                    android:text="Q1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                     />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btwo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3f51b5"
                    android:text="Q2" />

            </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2" > 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"           
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rtwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="3"
        android:numStars="3"
        android:progressTint="#FFD700"
        android:stepSize="3" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- second -->
 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/three"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:weightSum="3" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bthree"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3f51b5"
                    android:text="Q3" />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                     />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bfour"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3f51b5"
                    android:text="Q4" />

            </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/four"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rthree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="3"
        android:numStars="3"
        android:progressTint="#FFD700"
        android:stepSize="3" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rfour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="3"
        android:numStars="3"
        android:progressTint="#FFD700"
        android:stepSize="3" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- third -->

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/five"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:weightSum="3" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bfive"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3f51b5"
                    android:text="Q5" />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                     />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bsix"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3f51b5"
                    android:text="Q6" />

            </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/six"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rfive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="3"
        android:numStars="3"
        android:progressTint="#FFD700"
        android:stepSize="3" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rsix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="3"
        android:numStars="3"
        android:progressTint="#FFD700"
        android:stepSize="3" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- four -->

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/seven"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:weightSum="3" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bseven"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3f51b5"
                    android:text="Q7" />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                     />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/beight"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3f51b5"
                    android:text="Q8" />

            </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/eight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rseven"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="3"
        android:numStars="3"
        android:progressTint="#FFD700"
        android:stepSize="3" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/reight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="3"
        android:numStars="3"
        android:progressTint="#FFD700"
        android:stepSize="3" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- five -->

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/nine"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:weightSum="3" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bnine"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3f51b5"
                    android:text="Q9" />

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                     />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bten"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#3f51b5"
                    android:text="Q10" />

            </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ten"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rnine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="3"
        android:numStars="3"
        android:progressTint="#FFD700"
        android:stepSize="3" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rten"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="3"
        android:numStars="3"
        android:progressTint="#FFD700"
        android:stepSize="3" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I'm not able to display the layout i.e scorefragment also.

Please help me.

Comment: check your xml ..you done mistake in ScrollView  child

Comment: BTW.. I've not used the ScrollView in my  fragment layout.

Comment: There is issue in your xml file, scrollview can have only one child view,means you have to add your all controls in one layout within scrollview

Comment: I've added activity layout file containing navigation drawer .Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrollview contains only one child...

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">   
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="#F5F5DC">

       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
                android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/thirteenone"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
                android:id="@+id/thumb_button_2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_2"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/thirteentwo"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="B" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>



                 <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                     android:weightSum="3"
                      android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                     <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
                         android:id="@+id/thumb_button_3"
                         android:layout_width="100dp"
                         android:layout_height="200dp"
                         android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_3"
                         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                         android:src="@drawable/thirteenthree"
                         android:layout_weight="1" />

                     <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/textView6"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_weight="1" />

                     <com.example.android.animationsdemo.TouchHighlightImageButton
                         android:id="@+id/thumb_button_4"
                         android:layout_width="100dp"
                         android:layout_height="200dp"
                         android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_4"
                         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                         android:src="@drawable/thirteenfour"
                         android:layout_weight="1" />

                 </LinearLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_weight="1" 
                     android:weightSum="3">

                     <CheckBox
                         android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="C" 
                          android:layout_weight="1" />

                      <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/textView4"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_weight="1"  />
                     <CheckBox
                         android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="D"
                         android:layout_weight="1"  />

                 </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_zoom_touch_close" />

    </RelativeLayout>
      </ScrollView>

      <!-- The navigation drawer -->
      <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

      <!-- Profile Box -->

      <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profileBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
            android:padding="8dp" >

       <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/avatar"
         android:layout_width="50dp"
          android:layout_height="50dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatar"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- List of Actions (pages) -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:background="#ffffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Yes..Even I've added before too. Please have a look at my xml file please

Comment: simple sorry for late you have given id to wrong view.....make "android:id="@+id/mainContent" to your frame layout id...

Comment: Yess.. Got the layout i.e layout has been displayed..:)

Answer (score 0):

In Your layout file you should have only one Layout inside ScrollView.

Comment: BTW.. I've not used the ScrollView in my fragment layout

Comment: @Karan can you post your layout file.

Comment: Okay sir.. I'll upload

Comment: I've added activity layout file containing navigation drawer .Please check

Answer (score 0):

Yep, as the others have said, it seems like you're adding more that one view to a `ScrollView` which is not possible. The good practice would be for the `ScrollView` to have a `LinearLayout` as its *only* child and then you add your desired widgets and views to that `LinearLayout`.

**Edit after you added the layouts.**
I believe the problem is that you are trying to load (or replace) your fragments onto a `ScrollView`. I tried looking at the source code for the `replace` method and it seems that it adds your fragment's layout to the parent (in this case a `ScrollView`) and hides the other children (It does not delete them, thus the `IllegalStateException` exception). It actually does not delete the other children because you might want to manipulate them later.

In your case, you must replace your fragments with the content of the `ScrollView` (which should be a `FrameLayout` for the reason I said earlier) not the `ScrollView` itself. Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: BTW.. I've not used the ScrollView in my fragment layout

Comment: Well that should make it interesting. Could you please post the your drawer and fragment's layouts? This would help identify what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Karan. One question though. What is the widget with id `mainContent`? Is is a `FrameLayout`? And one more thing, are you sure that layout is okay? There seems to be a `</LinearLayout>` missing at the end.

Comment: I've added activity layout file containing navigation drawer .Please check

Comment: @Karan, thank you. Please check out the answer. Tell me if it does not fix it for you.

Comment: Its very difficult for me trace out it theoretically. Could you please explain me more

Comment: Sure, essentially when you are using the `replace` method, you are removing the previous fragment layout from the container and adding your new layout (it's like calling `remove` a number of times and then calling the `add` method -- I got this from the documentation). Here, there is something wrong though. Because your container which is a `ScrollView` already has a child that was not added by a `FragmentManager` thus will not be removed by it. So when you are adding another layout to it the compiler raises an `IllegalStateException` exception. I hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104148/discussion-between-karan-and-mehrdadjg).

Comment: To resolve this issue you must use a container that can handle multiple children at a time, i.e. not a `ScrollView`. Even if you want to use a `ScrollView` as your container (which is better avoided) you must not add any children yourself but let the `FragmentManager` manage its content.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because **you are taking multiple childs inside your scrollView.**

**Try to merge all your layout inside a single Linear Layout inside the ScrollView.** This might solve your problem!

Let me know if this works .. :)

Comment: Here I'm using drawer layout . So it should be top of all layouts right?

Comment: I've done the same thing as you stated.. Please have a look at activity layout file

Comment: do one thing.. in place of FrameLayout. Try to use LinearLayout. Let me know if this works. I am here

Comment: Nope. Same problem..:(

Comment: yar i even copied your xml for testing .. for me its working fine ! can you send me your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104157/discussion-between-karan-and-vivek-kumar).